# Ordering results from threaded workers

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a library that I can poll to retrieve blocks of data. Each of the returned blocks have an index that represents the order the blocks should be re-assembled.

I have found that throughput can be greatly increased if I run multiple worker threads that poll the library and then push the results into some threadsafe structure like ConcurrentQueue to be retrieved by my main thread.

What I would like to know is are there any efficient methods I can use for the worker to check that is has the next block before pushing it into the queue, and if it doesn't wait until the event something is pushed into the queue and redo the check.

I can picture the brute force method being a while loop in the worker thread that peeks at the queue to check if the block just received = peeked block + 1, however this seems messy as the worker thread would always need to leave one block in the queue to be checked, and could result in multiple worker threads sitting spinning (presumably trying to get queue locks) if an earlier block is delayed significantly.

Comment: Create a priority queue and pop all returned blocks in there when you get a notification. If the returned block isn't the one you're expecting then ignore it. When it is you drain the priority queue until it's empty or you hit a block that isn't the next one in the sequence.

Comment: As in continue to pop blocks, if its the one I want use it if its not push it back into the queue?

Comment: No, it's a priority queue. The top one is the earliest one that's come back. If it's the one you're expecting next then pop it, otherwise wait for more results to arrive until the one you're expecting arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Instead of using a dynamically populated Queue (or other structures), you may consider pre-populating a list of request-response pairs in the correct order and then farm out the processing without modifying the order.</s>

Based on discussion, it's a produce-consume pattern. Let me know if I get these right:

1. The `Producer` gives out data *out-of-order*.
2. This data needs to be held in a buffer.
3. A `Consumer` continuously requests data from the buffer.
4. The buffer **internally has some logic to know what data needs to be handed out to the `Consumer` next**, which may not have arrived yet.

If so, then you may consider wrapping a `ConcurrentDictionary` keyed by the expected ordering of data.

```
class IndexedDataBuffer<TData>
{
  private long expectedIndex;
  private ConcurrentDictionary<long, TData?> dict = new();

  public IndexedDataBuffer(long firstExpectedIndex) 
    => expectedIndex = firstExpectedIndex;

  public void Add(long index, TData data) 
    => dict.TryAdd(index, data);
  
  public bool TryGetNext(out TData? data) {
    // If the next expected data has arrived, remove and return it.
    var found = dict.TryRemove(expectedIndex, out data);
    if (found) expectedIndex++; // Or however you calculate your next index
    return found;
  }
}
```

And the tester program running Producer & Consumer threads.

```
var firstIdx = 3;
// Items to produce
var indices = Enumerable.Range(firstIdx, 10000).ToArray();

// Buffer to hold the produced data.
// In this case, we'll tell it to hold string data.
var buffer = new IndexedDataBuffer<string>(firstIdx);

// Producer thread. 
new Thread(() => Parallel.ForEach(indices, i => 
{ 
  // Delay even numbered data, so items are added out-of-order
  if (i % 2 == 0) Thread.Sleep(50);

  var data = i.ToString("X4");
  // To prove the producer's out-of-order nature, uncomment the following:
  //Console.WriteLine($"-Produced {data}");
  buffer.Add(i, data);
})).Start();


// Consumer loop. This will always get items in-order.
while(true)
{
  if (buffer.TryGetNext(out string? data))
    Console.WriteLine($"Consumed {data}");
}
```

Comment: I had considered something like this but in this case I don't make a request for a specific block, just "Give me a block"

Comment: @Hugoagogo Oh, so you just say "gimme, gimme, gimme" and it gives you three consecutive blocks? But if you paralellise the "gimme" the 3 blocks may arrive non-consecutively?

Comment: Yes that is correct, from some very basic testing I get improvements up to about 6-7 workers, and results are "usually" in the right order, but I am guessing as things go through various network layers they can end up out of order.

Comment: If they come back with an index, why not simply dump the index-data tuple in a `ConcurrentBag`, and in the end do an `.OrderBy(item.index)`?

Comment: I effectively build a stream out of the returned data, some of which is plotted, or saved to file, the data may be requested indefinitely preventing waiting until the end and sorting.

Comment: Right. I updated the answer, maybe it's closer to the requirements now?

Comment: This is a very nice example, I wish I had though of using the dictionary as a nice way to be able to pull if we have data from a certain index. As a last question is there any way to improve the loop consuming the data to prevent it being a busy loop if there is a gap in returned results or blocks come in slowly. Not sure if there is something neater than just sleeping for 20ms if trygetnext returns false.

Comment: <s>Inside the `Add()` you could raise an event when the added index is the same as the next expected. Your Consumer can then just listen to it.</s> Wait, no, that was dumb. Sorry.

Comment: Of course, then when the item is consumed and the expected index is updated I can see if I should issue a bonus event. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Sorry why is it dumb?

Comment: With the whole asynchronous nature of the thing, you may have concurrent events and event handlers triggering, causing things to be processed out of order again. Try it out in the tester above :)

Comment: I think it would be ok if the event doesnt contain the data just a signal telling the consumer hey go check the queue it probably has data.

Comment: Yeah. You just shouldn't consume the data directly in your event handler, because you'll have multiple handlers firing off simultaneously. You'd still need a loop to ensure your consumer is sequential, but maybe instead of `Sleep`-ing, you wait on a `SemaphoreSlim` or `AutoResetEvent` which you can trigger from the event.